# I am not able to set the path of the class file which I am adding in the jar through code

Tags: java, executable-jar

```
public static int compileModifiedClass(String ModifiedFile)
{
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    int result = compiler.run(null, null, null, ModifiedFile);
    System.out.println("Compile result code = " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Path for ModifiedFile: D:\ModifiedJavaFiles\com\example\tests\

So, the classes are generated in this folder and Jar path is :D:\test.jar

I want to set the path for these classes in the jar as com/example/tests.

Any help would really be appreciated.

To add the info, after compiling the classes, I am getting the classes from the path and calling updateZipFile method to update the jar.

```
classes = getClassesFromPath(ModifiedFilesPath, JarPath);
                        File jarFile = new File(JarPath);
                        JarUpdater jarUpdater = new JarUpdater();
                        try 
                        {
                            jarUpdater.updateZipFile(jarFile, classes);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

public void updateZipFile(File zipFile,
             File[] files) throws IOException {
               // get a temp file
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(zipFile.getName(), null);
               // delete it, otherwise you cannot rename your existing zip to it.
        tempFile.delete();

        boolean renameOk=zipFile.renameTo(tempFile);
        if (!renameOk)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not rename the file "+zipFile.getAbsolutePath()+" to "+tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));

        ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            String name = entry.getName();
            boolean notInFiles = true;
            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                    notInFiles = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (notInFiles) {
                // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
                // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
                int len;
                while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
            }
            entry = zin.getNextEntry();
        }
        // Close the streams        
        zin.close();
        // Compress the files
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
            // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            // Complete the entry
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }
        // Complete the ZIP file
        out.close();
        tempFile.delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URL jar = jarFile.toURI().toURL();
URL dir = new URL("file:/D:/ModifiedJavaFiles/");
URL[] urls = { jar, dir };
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class<?> klazz = loader.loadClass("com.example.tests.MyTest");
loader.close();
```